# How to select a specific percentage of data in Octave?

Tags: octave

I want to select a specific percentage of data from a matrix. How to do it?
To be more clear:

I know that if

```
A =

    1
    2
    3
    4
    5
    6
    7
    8
    9
   10
```

then

```
A(1:7, :) = A(1:7)
```

will give me the 70% of data. 
I want to know if it is possible to write something like

```
A(70%, :)
```

Thanks

Comment: Yep... the solution is really simple. I don't know if it exist a built-in in octavev that do it, but I've bypassed the problem with simply applying percentuage definition:

    A(1:round(size(A, 1) * 70 / 100), :)

Comment: yes that is a solution. Please post as an answer and close that question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not the perfect solution (problems with dimensional matrix nxm with m size > 1), but is really simple.

I don't know if it exist a built-in in octavev that do it, but I've bypassed the problem with simply applying percentuage definition:

```
A(1:round(size(A, 1) * 70 / 100)
```

Comment: ;) You can accept your answer, see https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/accept-your-own-answers/.